# A matrix given by some parameters and variables. How to determine those parameters so that the matrix is independent of all variables?

Tags: equation-solving

For example, I have a matrix A given by some parameters (a,b,c,d) and two variables (x,y),
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}a&a+bx\\(c-d)y&a(c+d)\end{pmatrix}
$$
The condition is that A is a matrix independent of (x,y). Therefore, we find b=0 and c=d.

How should I do it in mathematica? Now I have a complicated 64-by-64 matrix with 32 parameters and 3 variables. So I want a general method to solve this problem.

Comment: Are the matrix elements simple polynomial functions of $x$ and $y$, or is it more generally complicated than that?

Comment: If the matrix elements are simple enough, it's *possible* that something like `SolveAlways[
 Flatten[A] == Flatten[A /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}] // Thread, {x, y}]` would work, although I don't know how fast that will be on a 64 by 64 matrix.

Comment: They are rational expressions of x and y. If we set all variables to 0, some denominators might be 0 too.

Comment: Can you give a more complicated example, then, one that shows the difficulty in the issue here?  Edit your post to include the example, properly formatted in code blocks with proper Mathematica notation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the derivatives of $A$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ to zero for all values of $x$ and $y$:

```
A = {{a, a + b x}, {(c - d) y, a (c + d)}};

SolveAlways[Thread[Flatten[D[A, {{x, y}}]] == 0], {x, y}]
(*    {{b -> 0, c -> d}}    *)
```